# no. of arguments in boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost-bind

How many maximum arguments can we pass to boost::bind()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

by default it's 9.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html#NumberOfArguments

Comment: And if you are calling functions with more than 9 arguments then you need to rethink your design!

Comment: @GrahamS I think boost.lambda bind takes up to 9 as well. Boost.Spirit.Phoenix, the library I use for functional programming, has default 10 w/a macro to define the upper limit.

Comment: I wrote an IOC system that required templates per argument used to construct objects. I think it ended up going as high as 12. Was probably too many

Comment: @GrahamS : sometimes you just have to consume headers from some commecrial external libraries where discussing the design with the vendor isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you can't switch to C++11, you should consider switching from boost::function to the TR1 functions, which was a preview for C++11

Basically, what started out as boost::function became part of the C++ standard library, which nowadays is defined with variadic templates. In a nutshell this means that there is no hard limit anymore (but you might need to define additional placeholder variables if you need something beyond `_19` )

To switch from boost::function to std::tr1 do the following

find all occurences of `#include <boost/function>` and `#include <boost/bind>`
and replace them by:

```
 #include <tr1/functional>
 using std::tr1::function;
 using std::tr1::bind;
 using std::tr1::placeholders::_1;
 using std::tr1::placeholders::_2;
...
```

This should work as a drop-in replacement. If you happen to switch to C++11 later, just throw
out the "tr1" part.