# boost::bind is sick complains for nothing

Tags: c++, boost, bind

i have tried everything this thing simply is pure non sense, really...
Here is the problematic code:

```
    CRoom* pRoom = &mRooms[pClient->iCurChannel][pClient->iCurRoom];
    pClient->bPendingOperation = true;
    pRoom->OnBattlePlayerRespawn(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);// doesnt copmlain
    pRoom->mMainData.mStrand.post(boost::bind(&CRoom::OnBattlePlayerRespawn, pRoom, pClient, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 55, 4563)); // complains, wtf?
```

OnBattlePlayerRespawn declared as followed:

```
    void CRoom::OnBattlePlayerRespawn(CClient* pClient, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot1, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot2, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot3, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot4, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot5, uint32_t dwSpecial1, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot6, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot7, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot8, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot9, uint32_t dwEquipItemSlot10, uint32_t dwSpecial2)
```

Compiler error:

```
    `Error      no matching function for call to `bind(void (CRoom::*)(CClient*, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t), CRoom*&, CClient*&, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)'`
    candidate expects 2 arguments, 15 provided
    pRoom->mMainData.mStrand.post(boost::bind(&CRoom::OnBattlePlayerRespawn, pRoom, pClient, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 55, 4563)); // complains, wtf?
```

"candidate expects 2 arguments, 15 provided" seriously? then why the regular call works then?
I cant really solve, help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [Docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.implementation.number_of_arguments): "This implementation supports function objects with up to nine arguments."

Comment: If i only read the docs before wasting my time...

Comment: Could you please rewrite your comment in an answer so i could accept?

Comment: related from 6 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955841/no-of-arguments-in-boostbind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no. of arguments in boost::bind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955841/no-of-arguments-in-boostbind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is simple -- you're trying to bind too many arguments.

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.implementation.number_of_arguments)

> This implementation supports function objects with up to nine arguments. This is an implementation detail, not an inherent limitation of the design.